# How to properly boil egg white?

Tags: eggs, boiling, egg-whites

I am trying to boil egg white. It's around 500gr. How to boil it properly?

In previous attempt, I boil it using a stainless steel container with no lid and put it in a pan filled with water. I screw up since the water is able to reach the egg. This method also time consuming because the container is not hot enough. It also hard to clean after I do this.

Are there better method for me to do this? The method should ensure the egg safe to eat (no salmonella). I dont want to use plastic to boil it.

Comment: What do you want to do with the whites in the end?

Comment: I think what you are referring to is [steaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steaming) rather than boiling, so I'll add an answer relating to that.

Comment: @Stephie Well, after it's cooked, I'm going to blend it to make some kind of protein shake.

Answer (score 2):

You could microwave it, put the whites in a glass container with a loose lid and blast it, the texture will be very similar to a boiled egg. You might have to check from time to time for doneness.

It will harden in the shape of the container if you don't "scramble" it every 30s, and it might also explode from the steam trying to escape (hence the cover). Brush some oil in the container to make sure the whites don't stick.

Personally for that much egg I'd just cook them in a pan like an omelet, it's much less trouble.

Comment: WARNING! Eggs have the tendency to explode in the microwave, especially if the yolk is still inside. Raw eggs have moisture in them that gets evaporated in spots where the microwaves are more concentrated. If the egg white is already set, the steam has no way to escape and blows up the egg. ALWAYS cover eggs (boiled or raw, sliced or whole) in the microwave to contain the mess.

Comment: @Elmy read my answer :)
Also the question asks specifically for whites, so I assume it's already out of the egg shell and without yolks.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your answer, it just mentions a lid as a side note and doesn't state the reason why you should put a lid on. This information is easy to dismiss by any person who never made the very unpleasant experience of having an egg explode all over the microwave. Giving a reason for your advice makes people learn and remember it better and gives them a chance to learn from your mistakes without having to repeat them.

Answer (score 1):

You could bake the egg whites in a nonstick baking dish at 150 °C/300 F, eventually coating it with a little vegetable oil or nonstick spray (I don't like that personally), as [this Quora answer suggests](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-make-hard-boiled-egg-whites).

Answer (score 0):

As the method you are describing is actually steaming rather than boiling:

There are two components in the question that are relevant to the answer: volume and sticking

For the volume, what you actually need is a container that will allow you to cook the egg white evenly in a relatively thin layer of about 2-3 cm (1 inch) depth, so as to increase the surface area:volume ratio. To do this you need a [large flat plate shaped container](https://barebonesliving.com/products/enamel-deep-plate-set) (similar shape to the one in the link) rather than a deeper pot. This allows much more exposure of the egg to the heat from the steam and subsequently lowers cooking time and evenness. You need to be able to suspend this over the water, so you need a large saucepan or wok with corresponding lid to hold the plate you are using and trap the steam so that the egg can cook. You also need a trivet to raise the plate with the egg out of the water, where it can steam rather than boil in the water. Something like the one in [this link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B075SXP2Z8) is best, in my opinion.

With regards to the sticking - there's not a whole lot that you can do about this other than use a non-stick pan or a seasoned iron dish. You can use a thin layer of oil (if you see it running you've used too much) over the surface of the dish to aid in stopping sticking, but I have found this to have varying success.